# Is there anyway to change textmode of clearcase view?

Tags: view, clearcase

I know when creating a clearcase view we can set the text mode to transparent,insert_cr or strip_cr.

I already created a view with text mode as transparent. Now I want to change the mode to insert_cr.

Is there anyway to change textmode of clearcase view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-tmode` option is only available on the [`cleartool mkview` command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm), not on the [`cleartool chview` one](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chview.htm).

So the easiest workaround remains to:

- save the config spec of the current view
- delete the view
- create a new view with the [right text mode](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_view_text_mode.htm) ([see guideline](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/glines_view_text_mode.htm)) and the same name than before